# Converting CSV Array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to convert a CSV file into a PHP array, somehow it joined all the things in a single string. I wish to start a new line with the * sign,end with the ",," and separate by using ",".

Here are parts of the csv:

```
*,Alerts,Alert,Type,Text,,,,,,phr_ccr,alert,Type,,
*,Alerts,Alert,Type,Code,Value,,,,,phr_ccr,alert,Type,,
*,Alerts,Alert,Type,Code,CodingSystem,,Text,,,phr_ccr,alert,Type,,
*,Alerts,Alert,Agent,Products,Product,Description,Code,Value,,phr_ccr,alert,Product_Name_CD,,
*,Alerts,Alert,Agent,Products,Product,Description,Code,CodingSystem,,phr_ccr,alert,Product_Name_CDS,,
*,Alerts,Alert,Agent,Products,Product,Description,ProductName,*,,phr_ccr,alert,Product_Name,,
```

Comment: Are lines not already separated by EOL characters?

Comment: fgetcsv would handle this just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if it helps:

```
$csv_name;#name of ur csv file
    $raw_data=array();
    $count=0;
    $csv = fopen($csv_name[$count_list], 'r');
    while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($csv, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        #your csv column names:
        $alert=$csv_data[0];
        $alerttype=$csv_data[1];
        #and so on
        $raw_data[$count]=$alert."#".$alerttype."#so on according to ur need";
        $count++;
    }
```